# Lodash map keys and values on an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

My code:

```
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2}
let result = _.mapKeys(_.mapValues(orig, (v) => v + 1), (v, k) => k.trim())
```

actual and desired result = {
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3
}

But is there a better Lodashy way of doing this?

Comment: probably not unfortunately: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2718

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This solution uses [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#transform), and it's a bit shorter. I'm not sure that it's better than your functional solution.

```js
const orig = {" a ": 1, " b ": 2 };

const result = _.transform(orig, (r, v, k) => {
  r[k.trim()] = v + 1; 
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Without lodash I would use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to extract the key and value, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to the required forms, and then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert back to an object:

```js
const orig = {" a ": 1, " b ": 2 };

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(orig).map(([k, v]) => [k.trim(), v + 1]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: personally i prefer your answer, i use this all the time now thanks to you :)

Comment: Just an FYI about using the short function syntax `(...args) => 'doing work'`.  I had an issue where this would stop on the first instance of `v` (in your example) being `false`.  To avoid this, encapsulate the logic in curly braces `{}`, so that it doesn't interpret the boolean value as whether or not continue iterating over all of the items in the collection.

Comment: @Erutan409 - good call. Indeed if the expression evaluates to `false`, transform stops. I've wrapped with curlies.

Comment: note that transform is pretty much just reduce with a few minor differences

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, this is how you would do it without lodash:

## Solution 1: Object.keys & reduce

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};
let result = Object.keys(orig).reduce((r, k) => {
  r[k.trim()] = orig[k] + 1;
  return r;
}, {})
console.log(result);
```

## Solution 2: Object.entries & reduce

If your okay with using a polyfill for IE, you can also do this:

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};
let result = Object.entries(orig).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
  r[k.trim()] = v + 1;
  return r;
}, {})
console.log(result);
```

## Solution 3: Object.keys/ Object.entries with Array.forEach

One of the main issues with the above approaches is that you need to return result with reduce statements. It's not a big issue, but adds to the number of lines. An alternative approach is as follows

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};
let result = {};
Object.keys(orig).forEach(k => result[k.trim()] = orig[k] + 1);
console.log(result);
```

or

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};
let result = {};
Object.entries(orig).forEach(([k, v]) => result[k.trim()] = v + 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};

function test(object) {
  let out = {};

  _.forEach(object, function(value, key) {
    out[key.trim()] = value + 1;
  });

  return out;
}

console.log(test(orig));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce you can do:

```js
var obj = {" a ":1, " b ":2}

result = _.reduce(obj, (result, v, k) => {
  result[k.trim()] = v + 1
  return result
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@latest/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

reduce is more familiar but IMO transform seems more appropriate here

Answer (score 1):

You could use a good ol' `for in` loop as it looks cleaner

```js
const orig = {" a ":1, " b ":2};
let result = {};
for (const key in orig) {
  result[key.trim()] = orig[key] + 1
}
// result {a: 2, b: 3}
```

you could even make it a one liner.. :)

```js
const orig = { ' a ': 1, ' b ': 2 };
let result = {}; for (const key in orig) result[key.trim()] = orig[key] + 1;
// result {a: 2, b: 3}
```